# Arcanist's Magic Aura vs Divination / Divine Intervention

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, aura

The Arcanist's Magic Aura can give false information about any divination spells.

1. I was wondering if you can use it on someone so that when he asks something from a god (Divination), you can just mess up the answer the god gives to him.
2. Furthermore, can you change something in a god's action (Divine Intervention)?

Example:
A player ask the god to punish a village for their betrayal: to specifically punish all of the people who killed someone in the past. With Arcanist's Magic Aura the player would change the god's sense, so he would not kill all of them, only those who appear to him as a killer (which is changed by the player with Arcanist's Magic Aura).  This would result in the god not punishing the killers, but the people whom the Wizard wants to be punished.  Can it, or does it, work like that?

---

Note: The name for the spell in PHB is *Nystul's Magic Aura*. *Arcanist's Magic Aura* is used in the SRD for OGL purposes.

Comment: Are you asking about the spell *divination* and the Cleric feature Divine Intervention?

Comment: (Nystul's) Magic Aura is pretty specific about what false appearances it can create. Are you sure you're not thinking about a different spell?

Comment: @Medix2 I am ask about both of these spells

Answer (score 4):

### This won't work

The [*Nystul's magic aura*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/nystuls-magic-aura) spell (PHB, p. 263; named [*arcanist's magic aura*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcanists-magic-aura) in the SRD) has the following options for its effects:

> [...] **False Aura**. You change the way the target appears to spells and magical effects, such as *detect magic*, that detect magical auras. You can make a nonmagical object appear magical, a magical object appear nonmagical, or change the object's magical aura so that it appears to belong to a specific school of magic that you choose. When you use this effect on an object, you can make the false magic apparent to any creature that handles the item.
>
> **Mask**. You change the way the target appears to spells and magical effects that **detect creature types**, such as a paladin's Divine Sense or the trigger of a *symbol* spell. You choose a creature type and other spells and magical effects treat the target as if it were a creature of that type **or of that alignment**.

The first sentence of each of these is simply a broad description of the power of the spell. The following sentences explain the *mechanical* effects of the spell. And thus, the spell only changes whether something appears to be magical and what creature type and alignment a creature appears to be. If you are not detecting any of those things, *Nystul's magic aura* will have no effect.

Detecting whether "somebody has ever murdered" is not determining a magical aura nor an alignment / creature type and so *Nystul's magic aura* will have no effects.

Comment: The Idea is that the God has to detect that he killed someone or not and the wizard would manipulate that "detect" so he appears as innocent.

Comment: @Razzah Yes but the *magic aura* spell can't do that. It only changes when detecting whether something is magic, what its creature type is, and what alignment it has. It can't change any other sort of thing such as detecting whether a creature has murdered

Comment: I see! And what about Divination? :)

Comment: @Razzah The *divination* spell is not detecting magical aura / creature type / alignment. So *magic aura* will have no effect on it. Hopefully I've edited my answer to clarify

Comment: Thanks for the Clarification!

Comment: So just to make it clear! Arcanist magic aura can only:
Change the creature type
Change the Alignment
Change how and object appear (Magical or not)?

Comment: Yup exactly correct!

Comment: Also! How does it change the creature type / Alignment. Like someone sees a person who is a human , but he thinks its a gnome? Also if he sees a priest who is lawfull good , he thinks that he is evil

Comment: @Razzah It only effects how they appear to spells and magical effects, not normal perception. The examples given are Divine Sense and *symbol* which detect creature type. So if those are used they will return a false creature type. When you actually look at a creature you are not using magic, Nystul's does not effect how a creature simply looks

Comment: Hmmm, it does not seem to be a useful spell to have. Do you have maybe an example where it can be used to trick people?

Comment: @Razzah You cast arcanist's magic aura on a shield, showing it to have an abjuration magic.  (Protection) you then head to meet with a person who seeks a magic shield and will trade you a magic dagger for one.  They cast detect magic on the shield and believe it to be magic. The question you have, then, is did they do something similar to the dagger before the meeting? :)